# Retrieve / get / extract document revision(s) with PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I have a signed document with several signatures and want to retrieve the first document revision. But also all "intermediate" document revisions would be of interest. Since according to the PDF Spec document signing uses the incremental update mechanism it is possible to extract all previous document revisions - but how does it work with PDFBox?

I searched a lot and also looked at the examples provided by PDFBox however couldn't find anything related. I am using the latest PDFBox 2.0.X Version.

Comment: It's not available. You'll have to do it the hard way, by looking for %%EOF. (But be careful: linearized files have two %%EOF)

Comment: I think a mixed solution is preferable.  The op can use pdfbox to read the byte range entries from the signatures, deduce revision sizes  from them, and then use standard file related classes to extract all these signed revisions. (Often people are not interested in all revisions but only the signed revisions. )

Comment: Yes that would have also been my approach...And also yes: The signed revision was what I was talking about...