# How to verify PDF signature after incremental update with pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox, signature

I am trying to use Apache PdfBox to sign pdf and verify signature. I use examples: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/

If I add, for example, new page to document, then Acrobat Reader says, that signature is incorrect (ofcourse, because document was changed). But, when I verify signature via pdfbox methods - signature is correct (because ByteRange of signed data does not cover incremental updates).

How I can check disallowed incremental updates (changed data, pages, locked forms, etc)? And skip check allowed updates, such as new signatures or unlocked fields.

Comment: PDFBox does not include revision comparison functionality out of the box. You can try and implement it, though, using PDFBox as underlying PDF library. Be aware, this analysis is non-trivial.

Comment: @mkl You mean, that after signature verification, if verification is "ok", I have to check data after sign manualy and to check that these are new signatures for example, and not data changes?

Comment: Correct. And please be aware that that is not trivial. Even Adobe's implementation (which kind of defines the standard) errs every so often.

Comment: @mkl, I am trying to understand, how to get changes of document... In notepad I see some %%EOF etc, so it was incremental changes.
But, how to difine by PDFBox what kind of changes. I mean, that I want to allow only signature changes, and forbid non signature changes. Something like revisions, maybe.
I have found question like a my, but also without answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257195/retrieve-get-extract-document-revisions-with-pdfbox

Comment: As mentioned above that task is not trivial. A complete solution actually is beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer which is why you don't find a good answer here. Some libraries do short cuts, e.g. eSignsture DSS renders different revisions of the pdf (except recent signature changes), but such short cuts are not very good at understanding the difference between allowed and disallowed changes. I could try and outline what one has to do but not present a finished implementation...